# Do Diphthongs occur in Georgian?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, georgian

I'm asking this question because of this study https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/A7DCF9606BA856FCA5CC25918ADB37EF/S0025100306002659a.pdf/standard-georgian.pdf which claims this

"Adjacent vowels are disallowed in

monomorphemic words, ruling out the possibility of diphthongs (Butkhrikidze 2002: 83).

When adjacent vowels do occur as in [girɑɔ] ‘mortgage’, the vowels are heterosyllabic."

But then on page 263 they transcribe the adjacent vowels in words like /ɡɑiɑɾɑ/ "walked" and /mɔixɑdɑ/ "took off" phonetically as [ɑj] and [ʉj]

how are Phonetic realizations such as [ɑj] and [ʉj] possible if the vowels are heterosyllabic? shouldn't they be something like [ɑ.i] and [ɔ.i]?

Comment: Phonology and phonetics are different things, so are the phonemic and narow phonetic transcriptions. The  narrow phonetic transcription reflects that the phoneme /i/ can be realized as an allophone [j]. This [j] belongs to the next syllable, so [gɑ.jɛ.ra] and [mʉ.jxa.da]. In the latter word, /mɔ/~[mʉ] is a prefix, and /i/~[j] belongs to the root, the morphemic border is between them so one can hardly speak about any diphthongs there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!